# Why does variable not pass when wrapped in a setTimeout

Tags: jquery

If intervalIsClear is true, the hoveredItemIndex is picking up the index of the LI element fine.

If intervalIsClear is false, it is hoveredItemIndex is declared inside a setTimeout(), but is returning -1. Why can't it find the index once it is wrapped in a setTimeout()?

```
function()
                {
                    if (intervalIsClear == true){

                        hoveredItemIndex = $('.menu li').index(this);
                        changeToHoverText();
                    } else {
                        hello = setTimeout(function(){
                            hoveredItemIndex = $('.menu li').index(this);
                            alert (hoveredItemIndex);
                            changeToHoverText();
                        },500);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because when the function is executed a callback for `setTimeout` the execution context of the method is changed. Which means that the `this` variable inside and outside the `setTimeout` callback points to different objects.

Use [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to manually assign the execution context of a callback method

```
function () {
    if (intervalIsClear == true) {

        hoveredItemIndex = $('.menu li').index(this);
        changeToHoverText();
    } else {
        hello = setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
            hoveredItemIndex = $('.menu li').index(this);
            alert(hoveredItemIndex);
            changeToHoverText();
        }, this), 500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer just missing some bold ;)

Answer (score 4):

Because the execution context has changed in your `setTimeout` function. Remember in javascript, the `this` keyword is the context of the function execution. In your case the `this` object was the `window` object.

```
    var self = this;

    if (intervalIsClear == true){
        hoveredItemIndex = $('.menu li').index(this);
        changeToHoverText();
    } else {
        hello = setTimeout(function(){
            hoveredItemIndex = $('.menu li').index(self);
            alert (hoveredItemIndex);
            changeToHoverText();
        },500);
    }
```

So calling `setTimeout()` like you have above, you're actually doing this `window.setTimeout()`.

Comment: _"this" takes on the context on the calling object of a function_ is a false statement

Comment: There is $.proxy for keeping specific context, see @Arun P Johny 's answer. Maybe a closure could be used too.

Answer (score 2):

`this` in the callback of `setTimeout` is not same with outside.

You need to do with:

```
                var that = this;
                hello = setTimeout(function(){
                    hoveredItemIndex = $('.menu li').index(that);
                    alert (hoveredItemIndex);
                    changeToHoverText();
                },500);
```